# How should I create a data structure from multiple network requests in Haskell

Tags: haskell, wreq

I'm new to Haskell so apologies in advance for the potentially stupid question.

I'd like to build a data structure that is constructed from two http requests in my application.

My first request gets a basic list of users which I could choose to `decode` to `Maybe [User]`

```
 r <- getWith opts "https://www.example.com/users"
 let users = decode $ r ^. responseBody :: Maybe [User]
```

But if I'd like to enrich my user data by calling a second endpoint for each of the users that respond by doing something like

```
r2 <- getWth opts "https://www.example.com/users/{userid}/addresses"
let enrichedUser = decode $ r2 ^. responseBody :: Maybe EnrichedUser
```

I can't quite piece these parts together at the minute. I'm in a `do` block thats expecting an `IO ()`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: write a function with type `User -> [Address] -> EnrichedUser`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the type of `enrichedUser` is supposed to be `Maybe EnrichedUser` and not `Maybe [EnrichedUser]`, right?

If so, after extracting the `[User]` list from `users :: Maybe [User]`, the problem you're facing is running a monadic action (to fetch the web page) for *each* `User`.  There's a handy combinator for this in `Control.Monad`:

```
mapM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> ([a] -> m [b])
```

which can be specialized in your situation to:

```
mapM :: (User -> IO EnrichedUser) -> ([User] -> IO [EnrichedUser])
```

This says, if you know how to write a function that takes a `User` and creates an IO action that will create an `EnrichedUser`, you can use `mapM` to turn this into a function that takes a list `[User]` and creates an IO action to create a whole list `[EnrichedUser]`.

In your application, I imagine the former function would look something like:

```
enrich :: User -> IO EnrichedUser
enrich u = do
    let opts = ...
    let url = "https://www.example.com/users/" 
              ++ userToUserID u ++ "/addresses"
    r2 <- getWith opts url
    let Just enrichedUser = decode $ r2 ^. responseBody
    return enrichedUser
  where decode = ...
```

and then you can write (in your IO do-block):

```
r <- getWith opts "https://www.example.com/users"
let Just users = decode $ r ^. responseBody
enrichedUsers <- mapM enrich users
-- here, enrichedUsers :: [EnrichedUser]
...etc...
```

I've omitted the `Maybe` processing here for simplicity.  If enriching fails, you probably want to somehow coerce a regular `User` into a default `EnrichedUser` anyway, so you'd modify the bottom of the `enrich` function to read:

```
let enrichedUser = case decode $ r2 ^. responseBody of
    Nothing -> defaultEnrichment u
    Just e  -> e
return enrichedUser
```

and everything else would stay the same.

Comment: Having learnt a bit more about monad transformers `MaybeT` has proved to be useful to deal with this problem also.